# Space is missing in the Data Processing Addendum page content

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

In the [Stack Overflow for Teams - Free & Basic Data Processing Addendum](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/data-processing-addendum-free-basic) page, under the "**Processing operations**" section, there are some spaces are missed in the content.

In the below line, there is a space required in between "retrieval,recording"

> Receiving data, including collection, accessing, retrieval,recording, and data entry

In the below line, there is a space required in the "andsecurity "

> Protecting data, including restricting, encrypting, andsecurity testing

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Spaces are missing]